# Collapsing a percentage into ordinal categories using ifelse() in R?

Tags: r

I've been using R for awhile now and have computed variables before but this takes the cake. I've followed tutorials using mutate and ifelse to collapse my continuous percent variable into ordinal categories and I just can't figure out why all my values are returning 0. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? Here's some sample code:

```
SampleData <- data.frame(Percent = c(0.0, 0.20, 0.25, 0.26, 0.30, 0.50, 0.51, 0.60, 0.76, 0.80, 1.0))


SampleData$PercentOrdinal <- as.numeric(SampleData$Percent)
SampleData$PercentOrdinal <- as.numeric(SampleData$PercentOrdinal)
SampleData$PercentOrdinal = ifelse(SampleData$Percent == 0, 0, SampleData$PercentOrdinal)
SampleData$PercentOrdinal = ifelse(SampleData$Percent > 0 && SampleData$Percent <= 0.2599936, 0, SampleData$PercentOrdinal)  #What is wrong here? It makes all values 0. 
SampleData$PercentOrdinal = ifelse(SampleData$Percent >= 0.26 && SampleData$Percent <= 0.5099602, 1, SampleData$PercentOrdinal)
SampleData$PercentOrdinal = ifelse(SampleData$Percent >= 0.52 && SampleData$Percent <= 0.7599730, 2, SampleData$PercentOrdinal)
SampleData$PercentOrdinal = ifelse(SampleData$Percent >= 0.77 && SampleData$Percent <= 1.0, 3, SampleData$PercentOrdinal)

summary(SampleData$PercentOrdinal)
table(SampleData$PercentOrdinal)
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `&` instead of `&&`?  From the help: "The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector. ".  You also have a few gaps in your conditions, but I guess you know that.  I'd also be temped to use `dplyr::case_when` if you don't mind using a library

Comment: I guess & instead of &&

Comment: ... and in addition to Peter's comment, `?cut` will be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to suggest here:

- `&` does the comparisons you want and almost completes your code
- however, from the above the values `0.51` and `0.76` aren't included in any of your categories. Using `<=` and `>` for cut values in subsequent lines is probably what you mean to do.
- `cut` as suggested above would likely make this neater and easier to manage:

```r
SampleData <-
  data.frame(Percent = c(0.0, 0.20, 0.25, 0.26, 0.30, 0.50, 0.51, 0.60, 0.76, 0.80, 1.0))

SampleData$PercentOrdinal <-
  cut(
    SampleData$Percent,
    breaks = c(0, 0.26, 0.52, 0.77, 1),
    include.lowest = TRUE,
    labels = FALSE, 
    right = FALSE 
  ) - 1


SampleData
#>    Percent PercentOrdinal
#> 1     0.00              0
#> 2     0.20              0
#> 3     0.25              0
#> 4     0.26              1
#> 5     0.30              1
#> 6     0.50              1
#> 7     0.51              2
#> 8     0.60              2
#> 9     0.76              3
#> 10    0.80              3
#> 11    1.00              3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: you should have `right = FALSE` as the values you used are the lower interval values. eg 0.26 should be 1 and not 0

Comment: I'd selected those breaks without any clear knowledge of what the original question was trying to achieve. Reviewing it, presumably 0.25, 0.50 and 0.75 are upper limit values, so using these with `right = TRUE` would be most suitable? Have corrected.

Comment: Not really, note that anything below 0.26 should be in group 0. If you use 0.25 as the break with right = True, then 0.251 will be in group 1 but should be in roup 0. Just use the lower interval since its defined and use right =FALSE

Comment: As I say, I selected those breaks without any clear knowledge of what the desired output was and what breaks should have been (as 0.51 and 0.76 were excluded values). Had intended to wait for questioner's clarifications. But have edited back to the lower limit breaks and inserted `right = FALSE` as you suggested.